# Pagination for aws ec2 describe-images

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

When I try the following :-

```
import botocore.session
session = botocore.session.get_session()
client = session.create_client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_images')

client.can_paginate('describe_images')
False
```

I'm trying to get details about AMIs in a specific region. Even with filters it takes a lot of time to retrieve the required information.

Is there a way to enable pagination for describe-images ?

Comment: [xxyjoel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6525244) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68705798) saying "Looks like this is an open feature request [https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1991](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1991)"